# Spotted Image when render!

Tags: rendering

I've just learned Blender two day ago, and i have a problem hope some one can help me fix it, thanks.
when i render my image have some black spot, Here is image:
[image]

.
.
-I'm not good at english, Sorry! :<

Comment: The light source need more shadow samples, as you see in the screenshot, in the shadow panel change the samples to a higher value until you have a desirable result.

Answer (score 0):

You have what the community calls fireflies. Increase sampling and resolution to rid of it(Check picture for reference).

This is only possible in cycles render, which is the preferred and more photo realistic way to render. Click on the "Blender Render" at the top of your screen and then select Cycles. Note, the higher the sampling and resolution, the longer it will take to render[image]